# Have any prominent gurus explained the Buddha avatar as Maitreya instead of Gautama?

Tags: kali-yuga, buddhism

The common explainations of Buddha being Gautama or someone before us, have some problems.

For starters the date of Buddha is given in the Bhagavata as the start of Kali Yuga. This would either be before Gautama (and any sensible date for and alternative earlier Buddha, as it would mean he was alive at the end of the Mahabharata) or after us depending on if yuga sandhi periods are included. Also, the place of origin for the Buddha is wrong for Gautama (and arguably the parentage as well).

> Thereafter at the beginning of the Age of Kali He shall appear in Gayâ [Bihar] as the son of [mother] Añjanâ with the name Buddha for the purpose of deluding the ones envious of the theists.

P.S. While [this](https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin) has Maitreya (spelled Metteyya) interacting with a king in the far future, it never specifies when Maitreya is born or how long he lives. Thus, our time in relation to the Buddha Maitreya is left ambiguous. Also it seems to be metaphorical or simplified and would have been easy to misinterpret by the listener to says what Buddha says because of how alien the stuff being talked about would have been to him.

https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/maitreya
https://bhagavata.org/canto1/chapter3.html
https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin